# Do I need a headset for xbox 360 to talk to friends online?

Tags: xbox-360

Do I need a headset for the xbox 360 to talk to friends online?

Answer (score 8):

In order to voice chat with other people via an Xbox 360, you need a headset or [the Kinect accessory](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/kinect/speech-recognition).

[This Microsoft support article](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/xbox-live/chat-messaging) goes into specifics about what you need and how to get it set up.

[Microsoft makes headsets](http://www.gamestop.com/xbox-360/accessories/xbox-360-headset/40693), and so do a lot of third party manufacturers.

If you want your headset to also give you game audio, you'll have to buy one that has that specifically as a feature (like offerings from [Turtle Beach](http://www.turtlebeach.com/products/headsets/xbox) or [Astro Gaming](http://www.astrogaming.com/platform/xbox-360-headsets)).  Most "Xbox 360 chat headsets" will not give you game audio as well as chat audio, as the jack on the controller is specifically designed with mono chat-only audio in mind.